# Difference between two styles of Kotlin inheritance

Tags: kotlin

I have just started programming in Kotlin, and have come through inheriting classes and defining derived classes in two ways.

1.

```
open class Derived (var a: String="") : Base()
```

2. 

```
open class Derived : Base() {
var a: String=""
}
```

The Base class being this:

```
open clas Base( var x: String="")
```

My code works fine in both the cases,
however, I wanted to understand if there's any difference in both the styles or is there something I am totally missing.

Comment: The first approach makes `a` a parameter (with a default argument) of the primary constructor as well as a property. The second approach only makes `a` a property. Both approaches let `x` use the default argument.

Comment: they will generate different bytecode, but it will not really affect the functionality. Also in the 1st case you can pass value of `a` as an argument in Base i.e. `open class Derived (var a: String="") : Base(a)`

Comment: It does affect functionality. The second option has no constructor where you can pass an initial value parameter for `a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with inheritance. It's just two ways of declaring class properties.The difference is that in the first case you not just declare a property, but also allow to initialize it in primary constructor. So you may instantiate `Derived` like this:

```kotlin
val derived = Derived("123") //works only in first case
```

which is equivalent to:

```kotlin
//works in both cases
val derived = Derived() 
derived.a = "123"
```

Answer (score 1):

The first case you are passing a parameter `a: String=""` with a default value of empty.

The second case you are defining the string inside the class.

So it's about who knows the information.

If the class itself don't have the information, the first case will be used,
i.e. the class is dependent on ourside scope because it knows nothing about the information `a`

Btw, naming variables that you can understand easily helps a lot in long run. Please avoid using variable name like `a` for most cases.